# How execute a self contained rake build?

Tags: ruby, rake

We have an application which is compiled using Rake (on windows). We have a new requirement that one of our clients needs to compile the source code in their own environment using a bat file.

So I need to find a way to execute a rake build without installing anything on the host environment (i.e. everything required to do the build needs to be in the source directory, ruby, gems, etc...) from a batch file.

Anyone have any clues how I could get started with this?

Comment: Do you need to compile C extensions?

Comment: Nope, I just need to run pure ruby code

Answer (score 1):

Download and install ruby to a folder inside your project (do not add it to your PATH). After go to this folder and delete any "uninstall" file. Go to the folder again with the console (`cmd` and then use `cd path\to\ruby\folder`) and run `gem install ...` to install everything you need. After add a `.bat` file to run your app. Something like:

```
@echo off
rubyfolder\bin\ruby.exe myscript.rb
```

This is a fully portable ruby installation, you can put it in any computer and it will work as well. (I use it as a portable ruby in my pendrive to let me play everywhere with ruby!)

PS.: rake is a script from bin, you can open it with:

```
rubyfolder\bin\ruby.exe rubyfolder\bin\rake
```